# Code first migrations to create db schema when multiple, different SQL instances are used

Tags: sql-server, azure, entity-framework-migrations

I've searched both here and Google and don't find much on my issue, so either I'm not describing it properly or I'm the only one doing this in this manner.

I have a new MVC6 (.Net Core 2.0) project with multiple class library's. I have migrated the domain classes (using code first migrations) to a local db in my infrastructure project of this solution. I now want to test on my Azure test db. Aside from changing the connection string in the Startup class, how does one create the identical db on the new db (Azure test db)? Run the existing migrations on the new connection string?

I can't find much on this topic and could use some guidance as to the proper methodology for this.

Comment: Several ways. You could change the connection string and run the migrations as you suggest. You could generate a script. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0):

We use a similar approach to keep the database schema consistant for our environments, i.e loading different config files based on the hosting env (ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable) which contains the appropriate connection strings. During app startup the migrator executes the migration process to update the schema. However we don't use EF. We use FluentMigrator: https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Amila...that package looks useful but I see it hasnt been updated in almost a year. somewhat concerned its lifecycle may be not be that long

Comment: @dinotom unfortunately yes. The repo has not been update for a year now. There is another one if your interested: https://dbup.github.io/